# ctags best practicies

Tags: c++, vim, ctags, cscope

I'm working on +1M LOC C/C++ project on Solaris (remote, via VNC or SSH). I have a daily updated copy of source code on my local machine too (Windows, just for browsing code).

I use VIM and ctags combo (on both Solaris and Windows) but I'm not happy with results / speed. What settings for ctags would you recommend? There are a lot of options what should be tagged and how. Should I use single tag file per project, per dir or perhaps just one for everything?

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563616/vimctags-tips-and-tricks/563992#563992

Answer (score 1):

Using anything less than one for everything doesn't really make sense to me. Being able to quickly jump around your project is what tags are for in the first place. For instance, our code is divided into 3 main sections, Include/, Processes/, Libraries/. Without being able to jump between these I would be incredibly unproductive.

Personally I use cscope (its C++ parsing isn't great, but its ok, and its VIM integration is better than just ctags), but when I do use ctags I usually just add `--c++-kinds=+p`.

Answer (score 1):

I use etags:

```
find src1 src2 src3 | grep -v "\\.svn" | xargs etags --append
```

In emacs, position cursor on identifier and press M-. ([alt] + [period], or [esc] followed by [period]).

I don't know how it compares to your setup as far as speed goes, or if you're willing to use emacs. I'm just posting in case you want to try some alternatives.