# Vim and Ctags tips and tricks

Tags: vim, ctags, vim-macros

I have just installed [Ctags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctags) (to help with C++ development) with my Vim (or rather gVim), and would like to find out your favorite commands, macros, shortcuts, tips that go along with it...

Share your best arsenal. What other Vim add-ons you would recommend for C++ on Vim development?

**EDIT** What other add-on you would use in conjunction with Ctags?

**EDIT2** What version of gVim you use with tags? Does it make a difference?

**EDIT3** How do you enhance your programming experience for both big and small projects?

Comment: Make sure you're using exuberant ctags (a modern implementation) for best results: http://ctags.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Perhaps the kev is not constructive?

Comment: So, I answer here : Try clang + supertab  + snipmate. It's like intellisense in vim ! http://zwiener.org/vimautocomplete.html

Comment: though `closed as not constructive` almost two years ago, it is so constructive for me

Comment: I think the real reason for closing this question should have been: "This question, despite being enormously helpful, doesn't fit in StackOverflow policy of Q&A. Let this question and answers move to Quora and grow that site while we stubbornly keep closing helpful questions and answers".

Comment: The moment I saw this questions on google search result , I knew it would be closed as not constructive question !

Comment: `noremap <c-]> <c-]>zz`, just because I want the jump to be centered in screen ;)

Comment: I understand why this question was closed, given the rules of SO. But flagging a >400 upvote question with a >300-upvote answer for *deletion* is a bit on the grumpy side, isn't it?

Comment: I'm so sick of seeing questions closed as "not constructive" when they're obviously beneficial to so many people...

Answer (score 394, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> - go to definition
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> - Jump back from the definition.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> - Open the definition in a horizontal split

Add these lines in vimrc
    `map <C-\> :tab split<CR>:exec("tag ".expand("<cword>"))<CR>`
    `map <A-]> :vsp <CR>:exec("tag ".expand("<cword>"))<CR>`

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> - Open the definition in a new tab
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> - Open the definition in a vertical split

After the tags are generated. You can use the following keys to tag into and tag out of functions:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+`Left MouseClick` - Go to definition
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+`Right MouseClick` - Jump back from definition

Comment: C - ] => (control key) and ] key


 C - T => (control key) and T key

 Just for newbies to ctags. Thanks for new tab trick

Comment: Similarly, after splitting the window with `Ctrl-w C-]` you can do `C-w T` (aka Shift-t) to change that split into a new tab.

Comment: When I use your suggestion with "set tags=tags;/", it works in vim, but not in gvim. It says that it cant find the tags files. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Somebody still uses you MS-DOS: `tags;C:\` ? I feel like you might have been joking..

Comment: Hm.. one drawback to this is that when there isn't a tag, a new tab/split is still opened up.

Comment: Similar to your maps, vim has a `:ptag` command that opens the definition in a preview window.

Comment: how do i get the A-] to work on Os X?

Comment: @Will If you are using vim from the terminal then you have to change the terminal preferences to make option key behave like an alt key. If you are using MacVim then add this line to vimrc 'set macmeta'. There is doc for macmeta, :h macmeta.

Comment: `g C-]` is very useful. It opens a quick dialog to select one between multiple definitions.

Comment: `g]` is also useful. You can position the cursor over the tag name and press `g]` to get a list of matching tags.

Comment: also `set splitright` might be useful. commands would be executed in a right window after split

Comment: `vim -t <tag>` also quite useful: it opens vim on the tag

Answer (score 176):

One line that always goes in my .vimrc:

```
set tags=./tags;/
```

This will look in the current directory for "tags", and work up the tree towards root until one is found.  IOW, you can be anywhere in your source tree instead of just the root of it.

Comment: Going up to root is excessive. I suggest only going up to home instead: tags+=tags;$HOME

Comment: The source trees I work on aren't always in my home directory... and being that $HOME tends to be two directories away from root... well, I can afford two more directory lookups. :)

Comment: I agree w/ uzi. If my cwd is /home/me/programming/foo/bar/baz/bang/bam that's only 8 directory lookups. I suppose it depends on your tolerance for speed, but the time to lookup 1 directory isn't noticeably different from 8 on my machine.

Comment: I put my tags into a subdirectory, but use a similar trick (that yields the same fix mentioned by @Amit), `set tags=_tags/tags;c:/work`

Comment: It does depend on your scenario, I need to use gotgenes suggestion on one of my machines because there are roughly 8,000 directories in /home, and that tends to be a bit sluggish.

Comment: Is there something similar for `cscope`?

Comment: You don't even need `/` if you go up to root directory. Just `;` is enough.

Answer (score 45):

Another useful plugin for C development is [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/)
Just as Ctags lets you jump to definitions, Cscope jumps to the *calling* functions.

If you have cscope in your ~/bin/ directory, add the following to your .vimrc and use g^] to go to the calling function (see :help cscope).

```
if has("cscope")
    set csprg=~/bin/cscope
    set csto=0
    set cst
    set nocsverb
    " add any database in current directory
    if filereadable("cscope.out")
        cs add cscope.out
        " else add database pointed to by environment
    elseif $CSCOPE_DB != ""
        cs add $CSCOPE_DB
    endif
endif
```

Almost forgot... Just as ctags - you have to generate (and periodically update) the database. I use the following script

```
select_files > cscope.files
ctags -L cscope.files
ctags -e -L cscope.files
cscope -ub -i cscope.files
```

Where 'select_files' is another script that extracts the list of C and header files from the Makefile. This way I index only the files actually used by the project.

Comment: What is the advantage of cscope over ctags? Do they compliment eachother?

Comment: They complement each other. Ctags finds the definition of a symbol or a function. Cscope can find all the places calling a function. using both of them makes navigation in large source trees very easy.

Comment: However, AFAIK cscope has a limited comprehension of C++.

Comment: It is limited, and not very good. But for what it does (jumping to USAGES), there isn't any better alternative. Its main problem is that when you want to jump to function calls (f), you often need to jump to anywhere that symbol is used (s) instead and filter the results mentally...

Comment: ...because it hates namespaces. Global is also workable, but IMO slightly worse.

Comment: Can you show an example of select_files scripts ?

Comment: @Whaledawg Yes, when I press CTRL+] my sound card sends "clap.wav" in output :)

Comment: @vehomzzz: nimrodm does something fancier with his makefiles, but you could just use find: `find . -type f \( -iname "*.cpp" -o -iname "*.h" \)`

Answer (score 27):

You can add directories to your ctags lookup.  For example, I have a ctags index built for Qt4, and have this in my .vimrc:

```
set tags+=/usr/local/share/ctags/qt4
```

Answer (score 23):

All of the above and...

code_complete : function parameter complete, code snippets, and much more.

- http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1764

taglist.vim : Source code browser (supports C/C++, java, perl, python, tcl, sql, php, etc)

- http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=273

Comment: I think it would be good to add that taglist.vim is the most downloaded vim plugin.

Answer (score 16):

I use ALT-left and ALT-right to pop/push from/to the tag stack.

```
" Alt-right/left to navigate forward/backward in the tags stack
map <M-Left> <C-T>
map <M-Right> <C-]>
```

If you use `hjkl` for movement you can map `<M-h>` and `<M-l>` instead.

Comment: isn't the same as ctrl -] and ctrl-t -- I guess, your suggestion is a bit cleaner.

Comment: @Sasha, Pardon?  Don't know what you're saying.  =X  To note, this also works in :help.

Comment: I think this is more intuitive and cleaner than the default.

Comment: @Ayman But also violates the principle of not having to move the hands off the homerow, like using hjkl vs the arrow keys.

Comment: @TankorSmash, what principle?

Answer (score 10):

**Several definitions of the same name**

`<C-w>g<C-]>` open the definition in a split, but also do `:tjump` which either goes to the definition or, if there are several definitions, presents you with a list of definitions to choose from.

Comment: Similar to the first command, vim has a `:ptag` command that opens the definition in a preview window.

Comment: The preview window is nice because you can close it with :pc from any other window, without having to first move the cursor to the preview window.

Comment: There's also a neat autocmd trick with ptag at `:h CursorHold-example` which displays the tag for the item under the cursor in the preview window after a configurable timeout.

Comment: +1 for
 :tjump
i've now bound
 :tjump <C-r><C-w><CR>
works better than <C-]> imho

Would love to combine this behaviour with :ptag

Comment: `:help` is awesome sometimes...  
see `:help CTRL-W_g}` and `:ptjump`

Answer (score 8):

The command I am using most is C-] which jumps to the definition of the function under the cursor. You can use it more often to follow more calls. After that, C-o will bring you back one level, C-i goes deeper again.

Comment: C-t goes back one level in the C-] stack, while C-o goes back to a previous cursor position after a movement. So if you C-] to a function then page down, C-t will go back immediately while C-o will go back to the start of the function, *then* back to the call.

Answer (score 6):

I've found the [taglist](http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/) plug-in a must-have. It lists all tags that it knows about (files that you have opened) in a seperate window and makes it very easy to navigate larger files.

I use it mostly for Python development, but it can only be better for C/C++.

Answer (score 5):

I've encapsulated tags manipulation in an [experimental plugin](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse/#svn/tags/trunk) of mine.

Regarding C++ development in vim, I've already answered [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149558/recommended-vim-plugins-for-c-coding/152448#152448): I use my own suite, and a few other plugins.

Answer (score 5):

I've been adapting my vim plugins for two years to support big enough c++ project. You can take a look at them.

They use ctags and cscsope.

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1638
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2507

Answer (score 4):

I put the following in my .gvimrc file, which searches up the tree from any point for a tags file when gvim starts:

```
function SetTags()
    let curdir = getcwd()

    while !filereadable("tags") && getcwd() != "/"
        cd ..
    endwhile

    if filereadable("tags")
        execute "set tags=" . getcwd() . "/tags"
    endif

    execute "cd " . curdir
endfunction

call SetTags()
```

I then periodically regenerate a tags file at the top of my source tree with a script that looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -regex ".*\.\(c\|h\|hpp\|cc\|cpp\)" -print | ctags --totals --recurse --extra="+qf" --fields="+i" -L -
```

Comment: You just re-invented upward search. See :h file-searching. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563616/vimctags-tips-and-tricks/741486#741486

Answer (score 2):

I use vim in macos, and the original ctags doesn't work well, so I download newest and configure make make install it.
I install ctgas in /usr/local/bin/ctags(to keep original one)

```
"taglist
let Tlist_Ctags_Cmd = "/usr/local/bin/ctags"
let Tlist_WinWidth = 50
map <leader>ta :TlistToggle<cr>
map <leader>bta :!/usr/local/bin/ctags -R .<CR>
set tags=tags;/
map <M-j> <C-]>
map <M-k> <C-T>
```

Answer (score 1):

I adapted the SetTags() search function above (which should be replaced by the equivalent `set tags+=./tags;/`) to work for cscope. Seems to work!

```
"cscope file-searching alternative
function SetCscope()
    let curdir = getcwd()

    while !filereadable("cscope.out") && getcwd() != "/"
            cd ..
                endwhile

    if filereadable("cscope.out")
            execute "cs add " . getcwd() . "/cscope.out"
                endif

    execute "cd " . curdir
    endfunction

call SetCscope()
```

Comment: As gotgenes said, You just re-invented upward search. See :h file-searching. See [this plugin](https://github.com/pydave/daveconfig/blob/master/multi/vim/.vim/after/plugin/tagfilehelpers.vim#L14) for a relevant example.

Answer (score 1):

Another iteration on the SetCscope() function above. That sets cscope pre-path to get matches without being on the dir where "cscope.out" is:

```
function s:FindFile(file)
    let curdir = getcwd()
    let found = curdir
    while !filereadable(a:file) && found != "/"
        cd ..
        let found = getcwd()
    endwhile
    execute "cd " . curdir
    return found
endfunction

if has('cscope')    
    let $CSCOPE_DIR=s:FindFile("cscope.out")
    let $CSCOPE_DB=$CSCOPE_DIR."/cscope.out"
    if filereadable($CSCOPE_DB)
        cscope add $CSCOPE_DB $CSCOPE_DIR
    endif

    command -nargs=0 Cscope !cscope -ub -R &
endif
```

Comment: As gotgenes said, You just re-invented upward search. See :h file-searching. See [this plugin](https://github.com/pydave/daveconfig/blob/master/multi/vim/.vim/after/plugin/tagfilehelpers.vim#L14) for a relevant example.