# Where in vim help can I find all abreviations for keys like Ctrl, alt, etc?

Tags: vim, keyboard

In [Vim and ctags tips and tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563616/vim-and-ctags-tips-and-tricks), there are some mappings like:

```
map <C-\> :tab split<CR>:exec("tag ".expand("<cword>"))<CR>
map <A-]> :vsp <CR>:exec("tag ".expand("<cword>"))<CR>
```

From experience, I know that `<CR>` is `"Carriage Return"`, and `<C-/>` is `Ctrl+\`. But what is `<A-]>`? And where can I find in vim's docs all of this keyboard keys abbreviations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:help notation`

You have to scroll down a bit to give you the table that you want but it's all there.  `<A-]>` is `Alt + ]`

Comment: A is the same as meta key. What exactly is meta key, is just another name to alt?

Comment: Yes, Alt is the same as Meta in most cases.