# Function definition

Tags: linux, vi

How to get the function definition in c++ code using vi editor???

In c++ windows we can right click on function(i.e. where function gets called) then we select the function definition and can go to its definition.

But how we can do it in vi editor?????

Answer (score 2):

Both `vim` and `vi` support `ctags`.

Install [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/), open a shell in the directory where your source code lives, and run `ctags -R`.

Then you can run:

```
vim -t <function name>
```

or inside vim, move the cursor over the function name and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>.

---

For more information, you can run

```
:help tag-matchlist
```

which will display other keyboard shortcuts and commands that you might find helpful if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> doesn't do exactly what you want.

See also: [Vim and Ctags tips and tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563616/vim-and-ctags-tips-and-tricks)