# vim and Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim, text-editor

I have got Mac on work, Ubuntu on my notebook, CentOS on my server, Windows at my girlfriend place and my VM. I used to work on `gMate` (Ubuntu) that is very good and not far from `TextMate` (on my Mac), `e.texteditor` (Windows) and `nano` on CentOs. Now I want to install one editor for all my environments. I can choose vim or emacs. I think vim is more simple to manage :).

I know that there are a bunch of rails castomizations (plugins): from Akita, scrooloose, Pope etc. I've tasted all of them sometime ago. All of them was buggy (I think the problem is in my hands).

So what I really need now is to choose one plugin which is simple to install.

And second big deal is set of your favorite vim commands like:

- Open folder as project (and open the folder as project and exclude some subfolders from public dir)
- Fast open file from my project
- Open reffering controller/model/helper/etc
- Extract partial
- Using snippets
- Code autocomplete
- Rails console / Terminal / Git support
- Working with tabs

and other useful stuff from *Mates.

And I want to set vim face: like file manager on the left, console on the bottom etc. What should I do for it.

**After bounty: Thanks to everybody! Going to win the vim!**

Comment: Have you considered [redcar](http://www.redcareditor.com)? It's written in JRuby specifically for rails dev and can be installed by gem install redcar. Redcar install

Comment: I have got Redcar but it is still buggy and crashes periodically. And it looks pretty encouraging

Comment: Try this out: http://www.codeulatescreencasts.com/products/vim-for-rails-developers

Comment: Once you figure your vim config out this tip may help: Many people use tools like Dropbox or an open GitHub repo to sync their vim config between machines. I personally sync mine to three machines automatically with DropBox then sync to GitHub to share with others. Most .vimrc and .vim/ configs tend to be constantly evolving, so syncing them can save tons of time.

Comment: what do you mean by "working with tabs"?

Comment: There should be tabs :) so I can open number of files in tabs :)

Comment: @fl00r All modern versions of vim support tabs. On MacVim/Gvim tab switching is bound to the same key commands as the os uses elsewhere. Rails.vim and command t also support many tab and split command variations.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Edit: Actually someone already mentioned janus, but I am leaving this up because it has more info on what janus is.

I am a bit surprised no one has mentioned the vim 'distribution' Janus yet:

https://github.com/carlhuda/janus

Named after the God of Beginnings and Ends, it includes many of the plugins that people have mentioned above. While I don't use it myself it gets high marks from co-workers who are now former textmate users. Frankly if I didn't already have so much invested in my own vim configuration I would totally use it.

It is really oriented at Ruby/Rails developers switching from Textmate to vim. It has things like the command t(find file) and the project drawer bound to the commands you are already familiar with from Textmate.

Janus is sort of like a gateway drug to vim really. It gets you comfortable with familiarity from Textmate then blows your mind with vim's power.

It is very easy to install on linux(gvim) and osx(MacVim), however I am not sure how it would run on windows.

Now go enjoy vim. :)

Edit: 
You mentioned you would like a terminal split as well, Janus includes the ConqueTerm plugin bound to command e for opening a terminal.

Comment: +1 for Janus. I am a convert from TextMate and agree that it's a solid way to get started and have a consistent UI between dev systems. I'm also a fan of having a good starting point and being able to easily tweak settings with separate .vimrc.local & .gvimrc.local files.

Answer (score 8):

[rails.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1567) for:

- Open reffering controller/model/helper/etc
- Extract partial
- Rails console (calling scripts easily)
- Code autocomplete

[snipmate.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) for:

- Using snippets

[project.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=69) for:

- Open folder as project (and open the folder as project and exclude some subfolders from public dir)

[command-t.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3025) for:

- Fast open file from my project

[fugitive.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2975) for:

- Git support

[pathogen.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2332) for managing all those plugins!

Answer (score 4):

You might want to try out the .vimrc files of Carl Huda's [janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus)

Answer (score 3):

I forked this at Github when I was getting started developing ruby apps using vim. Then I decided to maintain my own files.

https://github.com/akitaonrails/vimfiles

It has Tim's plugins, Nerd tree, Command-T, snipmate, fugitive, rails and a lot more besides.

It is maintained to support win, linux and mac users.

Here is the original article that got me interested.

http://www.akitaonrails.com/2009/04/27/the-best-environment-for-rails-on-windows-part-2

Answer (score 2):

And include [VIM ruby debugger](https://github.com/astashov/vim-ruby-debugger) in your list. Its very handy.

Answer (score 1):

I don't do Ruby but here are the plugins I use:

- autocomple: [AutoComplPop](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879) or the native omnicomplete: `<C-x><C-o>` etc.
- snippets: [SnipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540)
- opening files (+ buffer switching + buffer search): [LustyJuggler](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1890)
- git: [fugitive](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2975) or [vcscommand](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=90)

These plugins/native functionnalities might fit your other needs but I don't use them:

- project: [project](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=69)
- open controller…: [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) & <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563616/vim-and-ctags-tips-and-tricks/563992#563992) for more). I think Tim Pope's rails.vim has that kind of thing but more ruby-like.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle) from the beginning, and save yourself the trouble of manually installing Vim plugins. It is much cleaner than Pathogen imho -- like a Vim package manager. That makes trying different plugins to see what you like a lot easier.

Edit: Btw, here is my own [vim configuration](https://github.com/jbe/.vim).