# How to search the tags file and load it automatically when vim start up

Tags: vim, tags, editor, cscope

Vim is my favorite editor, when I open a php or python file in vim, the first command is:

```
set tags=../../../tags
```

or

```
set tags=../../tags
```

I think vim can do this automatically:

> first search ./tags, if it is exists, set it, if not exists
>
> search ../tags,if it is exists, set it, if not exists
>
> search ../../tags,if it is exists, set it, if not exists
>
> until it reaches the / or D: directory

However, I am not so familiar with the vim scripts.
Any of your help will be appreciated!_

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are a few comments on this particular subject on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563616/vim-and-ctags-tips-and-tricks).

Basically, this is supposed to work:

```
set tags=./tags;/
```

It starts with a tags file in the current directory and goes up to the root directory.

Type `:help tags-option` for more details.

Comment: Placing `,` does not work on my vim. i used semicolon `set tags=./tags;/` which works for me.

Comment: Wow. That was a super bad typo. Thanks for spotting it.

Comment: Check `:h file-searching` for this syntax.