# Where exactly can I find a complete reference of Vim `tags` option?

Tags: vim, ctags

I see two answers that talk about setting the `tags` option of Vim such
that it starts looking for the `tags` file from the current directory
and work up the directory tree until one is found. The command looks like
this.

```
set tags=./tags;/
```

Here are the posts that talk about it.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/741486/1175080
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6289891/1175080

This syntax uses a semicolon to establish some sort of range of
directories to search (i.e. start with current directory and end with
root directory).

In the fact in the comment to the answer in the first link, there is a
comment that says,

> You don't even need `/` if you go up to root directory. Just `;` is enough.

Where is all this stuff documented? I looked up `:help 'tags` and I find
none of this mentioned.

```
                        *'tags'* *'tag'* *E433*
'tags' 'tag'        string  (default "./tags,tags", when compiled with
                |+emacs_tags|: "./tags,./TAGS,tags,TAGS")
            global or local to buffer |global-local|
    Filenames for the tag command, separated by spaces or commas.  To
    include a space or comma in a file name, precede it with a backslash
    (see |option-backslash| about including spaces and backslashes).
    When a file name starts with "./", the '.' is replaced with the path
    of the current file.  But only when the 'd' flag is not included in
    'cpoptions'.  Environment variables are expanded |:set_env|.  Also see
    |tags-option|.
    "*", "**" and other wildcards can be used to search for tags files in
    a directory tree.  See |file-searching|.  E.g., "/lib/**/tags" will
    find all files named "tags" below "/lib".  The filename itself cannot
    contain wildcards, it is used as-is.  E.g., "/lib/**/tags?" will find
    files called "tags?".  {not available when compiled without the
    |+path_extra| feature}
    The |tagfiles()| function can be used to get a list of the file names
    actually used.
    If Vim was compiled with the |+emacs_tags| feature, Emacs-style tag
    files are also supported.  They are automatically recognized.  The
    default value becomes "./tags,./TAGS,tags,TAGS", unless case
    differences are ignored (MS-Windows).  |emacs-tags|
    The use of |:set+=| and |:set-=| is preferred when adding or removing
    file names from the list.  This avoids problems when a future version
    uses another default.
    {Vi: default is "tags /usr/lib/tags"}
```

Where exactly can I find a complete reference of all the tricks I can
use with the `tags` option of Vim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Where exactly can I find a complete reference of all the tricks I can use with the `tags` option of Vim?

From `:help 'tags'`:

```
"*", "**" and other wildcards can be used to search for tags files in
a directory tree.  See |file-searching|.
```

`|file-searching]` is a tag, press `<C-]>` on it to find more about

> "*", "**" and other wildcards.