# Jumping to a file that is listed in Vim

Tags: vim

In Vim you can use the `[I` command to list all of the locations where a specified function, class or struct is declared or used. Is there a simple shortcut to open one of the files in this resulting list in Vim? I'd prefer not to have to type in the full filename and line number.

Comment: That's a great first question. Wish I had an answer! Oh, and welcome to stackoverflow ;)

Answer (score 5):

I remembered [the old gF trick](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_file_under_cursor), that works great.

Shameless rip from vim tips:

The following commands open the file with the cursor on the specified line number:

```
gF   open in the same window
<c-w>F   open in a new window (Ctrl-w F)
<c-w>gF  open in a new tab (Ctrl-w gF)
```

When such file-name/line number pairs are the result of compiling code, the following commands are also useful:

```
:help :cn
:help :cl
:help :cfile
```

The file:line plugin allows you to use combinations of file name and line number, like global.h:123, as an argument to Vim. When you open file:line, the script checks if file exists and line is a number. If so, Vim opens file at the correct line line number.

Comment: This works great most of the time,  when filenames are relative to the file you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

I use ctags in vim, which lets me use `C-]` to jump to a function/struct/whatever definition. You can use [these simple steps](http://amix.dk/blog/post/19329) to set it up, and once you have, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563616/vim-and-ctags-tips-and-tricks) has a bunch of useful shortcuts listed.

Actually, [that question I just mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563616/vim-and-ctags-tips-and-tricks) has a whole lot of tips which you might find useful (not just ctags related).

Answer (score 0):

It's not very ergonomic, but after closing the list `<C-w>i` opens a new window with the cursor positioned on the first instance of the word.

Adding a count like `3<C-w>i` opens a new window with the cursor positioned on the third instance of the word.