# vim editor, navigate at the source code using a log file

Tags: logging, vim

This question might be very abstract, so apologize in advance.

I have a log file that contains lines that obey to a certain pattern (filename,line,function, trace statement). For example

```
file1.cpp, 12, function1, "we are in function 1"
file2.cpp, 104, add, "add function"
another_file.cpp, 300, function2, "This is a trace"
```

What I would like to have is the vim editor to split in two windows. One window has the log file and everytime I move my cursor to a trace line, the other window will open the real file in the correct line of code.

For example in the top window my cursor is at line

```
file2.cpp, 104, add, "add function"
```

and the second (vim is split in two windows) window opens file2.cpp in line 104 (at the center of the second window).

Is there any chance to use a structured file (a log file) as a "navigator" for the source code?
If yes, how can we do it in vim? If not, let's make it! (but I would not like to reinvent the wheel :-) )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you describe is called a quickfix window in Vim. You may be familiar with it from the results of the `:make` command. You can open a quickfix window using `:cfile`. The format is determined by the `errorformat` variable. Look up Vim help on these for more details.

For your example (filename, line, function, trace statement) you could do:

```
:set errorformat=%f\\\,\\\ %l\\\,\\\ %m
:cfile log.txt
```

The gratuitous triple backslashes are there to get around escape sequences in the `:set` command. The format translates to `%f\,\ %l\,\ %m`.

Alternatively, you could output your log in the gcc format. In that case, the default `errorformat` would be able to parse it, and all you would have to do is open it with the `:cfile` command.

After loading, you can view the log using the `:clist` or `:copen`.

Comment: This is exactly the correct answer; Making it complete i'd reference the 'errorfile' setting and the fact that you can launch vim with `vim [arguments] -q [errorfile]` to use the errorfile. (_Of course the latter assumes that a suitable errorformat is set in the vimrc file_)

Comment: Ok so basically the correct answer who be to create an errorformat matching the logfile format ?

Comment: @Xavier T.: either that, or the OP could modify the logging code to use an errorformat more readily recognized `my/path/to/file.txt:123:INFO no worries, just logging`, e.g.

Comment: I use printf("%s:%d, this is a before call6\n", _ _FILE_ _, _ _LINE_ _);. What my errorformat should be?

Comment: There is a default `errorformat` that works with messages similar to sehe's example. If you use that, then you will only have to to use `:cfile` to load your log.

Answer (score 2):

This is a non-trivial exercise, but it certainly can be done.

You'll need an autocmd to call a function on certain operations (in particular, when the cursor moved), something like this:

```
autocmd CursorMoved mylogfile.txt call LogFileUpdate()
```

You may also want to use CursorMovedI and others, but I'll leave that as an exercise for you... see:

```
:help autocommand-events
```

In the function, you perform the 'magic'.  This is untested and has no error checking; it's intended to give you something to play with and build your script from.

```
function! LogFileUpdate()
    " Make sure the cursor stays put
    let saved_view = winsaveview()

    " This is a slightly lazy way of making a consistent split: you could do something
    " clever here, working out whether there is a split at present and re-using it:

    " Close all other windows
    only

    " Get the current line into a variable
    let current_line = getline('.')
    " Split on commas:
    let parts = split(current_line, ',')

    " Get the filename and line number (removing leading and trailing spaces)
    let filename = substitute(parts[0],'^\s*\(.*\)\s*$','\1','')
    let number_str = substitute(parts[1],'^\s*\(.*\)\s*$','\1','')

    " Open the file at the required line number
    exe 'sp +'.number_str filename
    " Set the file type (doesn't seem to happen automatically in a CursorMoved autocmd)
    filetype detect

    " Switch back to the log file window
    wincmd w

    " Restore the cursor to its original position
    call winrestview(saved_view)
endfunction
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to navigate in source code with Vim is to use `ctags`

See :

- Inside Vim, `:help tagsrch.txt`
- [Browsing program with tags](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Browsing_programs_with_tags)
- [Ctags tips and trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563616/vim-and-ctags-tips-and-tricks)

ctags is an external program that will generate a list of identifiers for variable, functions, etc and Vim will then use that list to jump to the definition of function.

To generate a `tag` file, you simply need to run `ctags -R *.cpp,*.hpp` in your project directory. It will index every cpp and hpp file recursively.

Once your tag file is properly generated and in the tag path for Vim, you can "jump" to an identifier with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> when your cursor is on "functionName". ctags take into account the number of arguments but I think that using only the name it should work.

Then you can go back to your log file with either <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>.

It won't work exactly as you want to but you will be able to jump quickly back and forth between your log file and your code.

You can also search [ctags](/questions/tagged/ctags) on StackOverflow for more information.