# vim jump to structure/class definition

Tags: c++, vim

I have cscope and ctags in vim. When I place the cursor over a struct or class name, it shows me a long list of all the lines where that struct or class is being used.

I want to know if there is any way to jump directly to class or structure definition. Also, for a method like init, if I need to select it for a class, it shows me plenty of init. Is there any way to reduce the result to given class?

Comment: It is showing me long list. I just want to jump to the structure definition, not to the usage reference.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [YCM](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe). I personally find this solution so much better than ctags.

Comment: @mkaes: Its requirement is Vim 7.3+. I cannot update anything as I am working on shared environment where I am not sudoers. Hence, this I cannot use in the current scene.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563616/vim-and-ctags-tips-and-tricks?rq=1) that shows on the "Related" column on the right has several advices that you may find useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Cause:**

The default behavior of `ctags` when you press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>is to jump to the first definition. But it appears your cscope_maps.vim (`/usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/cscope_maps.vim`) contains the following line

```
set cscopetag
```

This will make vim display all the definitions available (Similar to `:ts`) in the way you mentioned in your question.

**Solution:**

1. Remove / Comment the line (If you are allowed to)
2. Use `:set nocscopetag` in vim
3. Set `:set nocscopetag` in one of the vim load scripts that loads after `cscope_maps.vim`

Comment: But please also add your comment and my problem into the answer.

Comment: Thank you!  I knew vim could do this because I'd seen it before, but I had no idea whether it was ctags' fault or vim's fault that I wasn't seeing the choice on some systems.