# Vim Tab next/previous shortcuts in OSX

Tags: macos, vim, keyboard-shortcuts, ctags

I've started using [vim with ctags and tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/563992/51197):

[image]

Adding the following to my `~/.vimrc`:

```
map <C-\> :tab split<CR>:exec("tag ".expand("<cword>"))<CR>
```

Opens the ctags definition of the current word in a new tab by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>.

However, tab switching is still painful and done manually with `:tabn` or `:tabp`.

I've tried the [following `~/.vimrc` shortcuts](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_tab_pages):

```
nnoremap <C-Left> :tabp<CR>
nnoremap <C-Right> :tabn<CR>
```

With no luck - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>←</kbd> do nothing.

**Any idea how map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>←</kbd> to tab-next and tab-prev in vim on OSX?**

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking is `gt` and `gT` commands.

```
gt  - takes you to next tab
gT  - takes you to previous tab
```

They can a take a `count`, for example `3gt` takes you to next 3 tabs.

Comment: The problem is not the command (`tabprevious` and `tabp` work), but with the key mapping.

Comment: Like @romainl siaid, Why do you want to remap it when `gt` and `gT` are already there

Comment: @romainl - you're correct, and thanks for the tip. However, I'm looking for a way to map the CTRL+Arrow keys, which are more convenient for me.

Comment: @AdamMatan, This is what vim mailing says http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/How-to-map-CTRL-Right-Arrow-td4838722.html . I would simply use `gt` and `gT`

Comment: @dlmeetei That's frustrating! I don't have PageUp/Down keys in my board. There must be a way to map them in OSX Vim.

Comment: Yep, What I wanted to bring into attention was to check if your key combination is being recognized in vim. In my case. It was not. I also was trying to map after your post. :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe I know what you mean Adam, if you're still there. I like to move slightly quicker without having to type a chord (`shift-;`).

Just to answer the simple question directly, the following mappings will map the ctrl-left and ctrl-right arrow keys to `tabprev` and `tabnext` respectively:

```
nnoremap <C-Left> :tabprevious<CR>
nnoremap <C-Right> :tabnext<CR>
```

Add those lines to your `vimrc` to make them permanent. This works for me in MacVim. You'll find more here: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Using_tab_pages

But you may like to consider the following as well. When using a single tab, mapping the "vim cursor keys" (hjkl) with ctrl for navigating horizontal and vertical splits / windows works well (`C-` means ctrl):

```
nnoremap <C-h> <C-w>h
nnoremap <C-j> <C-w>j
nnoremap <C-k> <C-w>k
nnoremap <C-l> <C-w>l
```

But if as I do, you tend to always use horizontal splits only, then you can just map `<C-j>` and `<C-k>` for changing between splits (up and down) and remap `<C-h>` and `<C-l>` (left and right) for changing tabs. Of course you can do the same with the arrow keys, or both!:

```
nnoremap <C-Left> :tabprevious<CR>
nnoremap <C-Right> :tabnext<CR>
nnoremap <C-h> :tabprevious<CR>
nnoremap <C-l> :tabnext<CR>
nnoremap <C-j> <C-w>j
nnoremap <C-k> <C-w>k
```

Some users may find the "vim cursor keys" closer to their normal finger positions, and also more consistent and intuitive. Some further suggestions are available here: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Alternative_tab_navigation

Use `:help map-overview` to understand the mapping commands better. `nnoremap` installs the mapping for normal mode only, and doesn't allow recursive definitions so the mapping is not re-mapped again.