# Ctags not working

Tags: ctags

I'm trying to understand a large code base. I need ctags to generate some tags so that I can jump to the function definition with `ctrl + ]`.

Unfortunately, after running `ctags -R *` in the source diretory where some python script files resides, then vi open the python script, then cursor on which I want to jump to definition of, but all prompts `E426: tag not found`.

I tried creating a `~/.vimrc` file, and adding `set tags=~/Downloads/fast-rcnn/tools/tags`, but still does not work, and when I open the generated tags file in the directory, seems only have tens of lines.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

turns out that `set tags=~/Downloads/fast-rcnn/tools/tags` missing colon `:`, adding it solve the problem, and follow the advice of [Vim and Ctags tips and tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563616/vim-and-ctags-tips-and-tricks)
I change it to `:set tags=./tags;/`